# android animate interrupt when parent view detach from window

Tags: android, animation

ViewA has a subview ViewB, markView has enter and exit animation, if ViewA move from its parent viewC and then add to ViewD when ViewB's animation not end, the animation end immediately and not exit.

```
    AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(false);
    AlphaAnimation enterAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 0.8f);
    enterAnimation.setDuration(800);
    AlphaAnimation exitAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.8f, 0.0f);
    exitAnimation.setDuration(500);
    exitAnimation.setStartOffset(3700);
    animationSet.addAnimation(enterAnimation);
    animationSet.addAnimation(exitAnimation);
    animationSet.setFillAfter(true);
    ViewB.startAnimation(animationSet);

    ViewC.removeView(ViewA);
    ViewD.addView(ViewA);
```

how can ViewB continue animation when ViewA remove from it's parent view

Comment: sorry, "markView has enter and exit animation" modify to "viewB has enter and exit animation"